# Changing class parameter with id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker, date-range

I found a function in internet to validate date range for my datepicker function it's work with `.checkin` and `.checkout` I want to set to work for id( `#checkin` and `#checkout`) and I know I have to change `.checkin` and `.checkout` with `#checkin`... but the problem is with getMaxDate and getMinDate function there are some js function that I have no idea what is it for example parentNode.querySelector and .className..how can I adapt my function for #id ?

[and click to see my project on codepen](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/bgyxRJ)

```js
$(document).on('focus', '.checkin, .checkout', function (){
    return new Pikaday({
   numberOfMonths: 2,
   field: this,
   format: "DD.MM.YYYY",
   minDate: getMinDate(this),
   firstDay: 1,
   i18n: {
    previousMonth: "Önceki Ay",
    nextMonth: "Sonraki Ay",
    months: ["Ocak", "Şubat", "Mart", "Nisan", "Mayıs", "Haziran", "Temmuz", "Ağustos", "Eylül", "Ekim", "Kasım", "Aralık"],
    weekdays: ["Pazar", "Pazartesi", "Salı", "Çarşamba", "Perşembe", "Cuma", "Cumartesi"],
    weekdaysShort: ["Paz", "Pzt", "Sa", "Ça", "Pe", "Cu", "Cum"]
   },
   maxDate: getMaxDate(this),
   onSelect: function() {
    e = this.getDate();
   }
  });
});
function getMaxDate(element){
  if(element.className=='checkout' && element.parentNode.querySelector('.checkin').value)
    return new Date(new Date(element.parentNode.querySelector('.checkin').value).getTime()+(15*24*60*60*1000));
else
  return new Date(2020, 12, 31);
  }
function getMinDate(element){
  if(element.className=='checkout' && element.parentNode.querySelector('.checkin').value)
    return new Date(element.parentNode.querySelector('.checkin').value);
  else
  return new Date();
  }
```

```css
.line{
 width:100%;
 height:10px;
 background:red;
 margin:10px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pikaday/1.5.1/css/pikaday.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form">
<input type="text" class="checkin" placeholder="Checkin" />
<input type="text" class="checkout" placeholder="Checkout" />
</div>

<div class="line"></div>

<div class="form">
<input type="text" id="checkin" placeholder="Checkin" />
<input type="text" id="checkout" placeholder="Checkout" />
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pikaday/1.5.1/pikaday.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the initial problem was the smallest one. At that point I did not realize another ***major*** issue with it:

- you were creating a new instance of pickaday on each `focus` event on your fields. That could never work.

So what I did was:

- I created a function that instantiates based on selector (from your old function).
- I run that function on both inputs, when the page loads.
- done! everything works as expected.
- Additionally, I streamlined the config object, the markup and the js to work with ids

Here it is:

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
    var picker = function(selector) {
            return new Pikaday({
                numberOfMonths: 2,
                field: $(selector)[0],
                format: "DD.MM.YYYY",
                minDate: getMinDate($(selector)[0]),
                maxDate: getMaxDate($(selector)[0]),
                firstDay: 1,
                i18n: {
                    previousMonth: "Önceki Ay",
                    nextMonth: "Sonraki Ay",
                    months: ["Ocak", "Şubat", "Mart", "Nisan", "Mayıs", "Haziran", "Temmuz", "Ağustos", "Eylül", "Ekim", "Kasım", "Aralık"],
                    weekdays: ["Pazar", "Pazartesi", "Salı", "Çarşamba", "Perşembe", "Cuma", "Cumartesi"],
                    weekdaysShort: ["Paz", "Pzt", "Sa", "Ça", "Pe", "Cu", "Cum"]
                },
                onSelect: function() {
                    e = this.getDate();
                }
            });
        },  
        checkout = picker('#checkout'),
        checkin = picker('#checkin');
});

function getMaxDate(element) {
    if (element.getAttribute('id') == 'checkin' && element.value)
        return new Date(new Date(element.value).getTime() + (15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    else
        return new Date(2020, 12, 31);
}

function getMinDate(element) {
    if (element.getAttribute('id') == 'checkout' && element.value)
        return new Date(element.value);
    else
        return new Date();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pikaday/1.5.1/pikaday.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pikaday/1.5.1/css/pikaday.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form">
<input type="text" id="checkin" placeholder="Checkin" />
<input type="text" id="checkout" placeholder="Checkout" />
</div>
```

Please also consider the current markup. That's all you need.

---

Comment: thanks it work's as I want and I have another question why didn't we change .querySelector .checkin it won't be use ? (I just wonder that :) )

Comment: The second part of the condition checks if the proper input has a value. When you press `#checkin` you want to look check if `input.checkin` has value and when you press `#checkout` you have to check if `input.checkout` has value.

Comment: yes..thanks it was works but know it is not working I don't understand why 
http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/WRBaRx

Comment: What those functions do is take the value from the element with class `checkin` and put it in the element with the id `checkin` (and same for `checkout`). If you remove part of the `DOM` it will no longer find the elements and will stop working :).

Comment: but I don't know how do I have to change my html or my js

Comment: do you mean my input must has .checkin and .checkout ?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to happen. It's not clear from your question. I just made it use id instead of class, as you requested. And you say it worked. What did you change and made it not work?

Comment: sorry..I change class instead of  id but it's not working for example :http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/WRBaRx I'm trying learn

Comment: It is bad etiquette to ask for additional work after you were provided with the answer to your initial question. You asked how to change and make it work with id instead of class, I answered that. You have changed the markup, My answer is clearly not going to work anymore because you no longer have the same elements in page. Maybe you should post another question regarding your new issue.At this point I don't understand how you want your code example to work.

Comment: no the function that you write it was work very well as I want and I didn't change my html markup it's same and I want to work it just id not class

Comment: Ok. wait a bit, I need to understand what's going on.

Comment: I finally understood what the problem with it is. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Updated the answer. No matter how small, I'm not going to accept another mod request. I practically fixed a completely different problem for you, that you didn't know you had but which was preventing this from working properly. And, no matter how you look at it, you just had to read the pickadate docs. I never used it before, but I went there, read the thing and understood what I have to do to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to jQuery!

Changes in `getMaxDate` and `getMinDate`

```
function getMaxDate(element) {
    if ($(element).hasClass('checkout') && $(element).parent('.checkin').val())
        return new Date(new Date($(element).parent('.checkin').val()).getTime() + (15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    else
        return new Date(2020, 12, 31);
}

function getMinDate(element) {
    if ($(element).hasClass('checkout') && $(element).parent('.checkin').val())
        return new Date($(element).parent('.checkin').val());
    else
        return new Date();
}
```

Changes in the function you are calling

```
$(document).on('focus', '.checkin, .checkout', function() {
    return new Pikaday({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        field: this,
        format: "DD.MM.YYYY",
        minDate: getMinDate($(this).attr('id')), //Change here
        firstDay: 1,
        i18n: {
            previousMonth: "Önceki Ay",
            nextMonth: "Sonraki Ay",
            months: ["Ocak", "Şubat", "Mart", "Nisan", "Mayıs", "Haziran", "Temmuz", "Ağustos", "Eylül", "Ekim", "Kasım", "Aralık"],
            weekdays: ["Pazar", "Pazartesi", "Salı", "Çarşamba", "Perşembe", "Cuma", "Cumartesi"],
            weekdaysShort: ["Paz", "Pzt", "Sa", "Ça", "Pe", "Cu", "Cum"]
        },
        maxDate: getMaxDate($(this).attr('id')), //Change here
        onSelect: function() {
            e = this.getDate();
        }
    });
});
```